# How to specify proxy server big ip f5?

Tags: f5-big-ip

We are attempting to setup a big ip f5 and need outbound internet traffic to flow through proxy servers.  Is that possible?

Comment: I think that's two different concepts. You're talking about setting up a reverse proxy, but then you're asking how to set up a forward proxy. If you're talking about HTTP replies in responses to requests that clients sent, those will already be flowing through the reverse proxy, since the reverse proxy opens a TCP session to the back-end server. What other traffic types do you need to go through the proxy?

Comment: no I need for it to literally send all traffic(software updates/licensing) to an existing internet proxy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to F5 Networks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will need to create a pool with the proxy server as your pool member and then create a virtual server for 0.0.0.0:80 with your proxy server pool as the designated pool for this virtual server.